# Memory leak on throwing an exception with a pointer member variable

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have the following problem:

Every time I throw the following exception, I am getting a Valgrind Memory leak warning:

I am was able to reliably trace it back to the `throw MyException{pointer}` statements I have in my program. - If I comment them out the warning is gone. I have multiple other exception classes that work flawlessly. The only difference between them is the existance of the pointer variable.

EDIT: I tried the same exeption with a std::string as an argument: The Valgrind error still persists.

The valgrind error:

```
144 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 7 of 15
```

(The file information points to the `throw MyException{pointer}` statements I already mentioned.

My exception:

```
// Forward declaration
class PointerClass;  

class MyException : public std::exception
{
public:
  MyException() = delete;

  MyException(PointerClass* pointer) : pointer_{pointer}
  {};

  MyException(const MyException& other) = default;

  MyException& operator=(MyException& other) = default;

  ~MyException() = default;  

  const char* what() const noexcept
  {
    return "my exception.";
  }

  const PointerClass* getPointer() const noexcept
  {
    return pointer_;
  }

private:
    PointerClass* pointer_ = nullptr;
  };
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: When doing `throw MyException{pointer}`, how is `pointer` initialised?   When the exception is caught, does the catch block ensure that whatever `pointer` points at is properly released?     If `pointer` is initialised using a `new` expression, for example, then it is understandable that valgrind reports a leak if the `catch` block that eventually deals with the exception does not do the corresponding `delete` expression.

Comment: The pointer is a pointer to a preexisting object, whose destruction is handled elsewhere. Therefore: No, I do not release that pointer when catching, as it is a member of a different class and is released on that classes destruction.

Comment: It is impossible to tell anything definite without having a [mcve].

Comment: @marober - Well, there's your problem.   You need to work out where the instance of a "different class" is being destructed.   Essentially, if it is being destructed late enough (or not at all) then `pointer` won't be released in time for valgrind to track it.   You haven't provided any representative code, so the best anyone here can do is guess.

Comment: Thank you all a lot! I managed to solve the problem: I used exit() in the catch statement, which somehow left the exception in memory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem: My catch was:

```
catch(Except::CustomException& exception)
{
  std::cout << "Exception occurred" << std::endl;
  exit(0);
}
```

Which was causing all the problems.
Now I use

```
catch(Except::CustomException& exception)
{
  std::cout << "Exception occurred" << std::endl;
  flag = true;
}

if(flag)
{
   exit(0);
}
```

Which causes no leaks.